# Calculating point spectrum of a $\ell ^2$ operator

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, operator-theory, spectral-theory

So I have the following operator: $A(x_1,x_2,x_3,...) = (x_2,x_4,x_6)$ and I need to find its spectrum and its decomposition so I started by calculating the point spectrum:
$$ Ax = \lambda *x \implies (x_2,x_4, x_6,...) = (\lambda x_1, \lambda x_2,...)  $$

So from here we can take any $\lambda \neq 0$ and get that it's an eigenvalue with the vectors of the form: $$ (x_1,\lambda x_1, x_3, \lambda^2 x_1, x_5, \lambda x_3,...)$$

Is this correct, does it mean that my residual and continuous spectrum are empty? Please don't provide me with a solution just point to my mistakes.

Comment: Note that the operator is bounded, so the spectrum is compact, so something must be wrong . A bit more concretely: If $\lambda>1$, I think it is not always clear why the vector that you wrote down is in $\ell^2$.

Comment: It is quite obvious that $0$ is also an eigenvalue. Actually your formula works even for $\lambda = 0$.

Comment: I forgot to check if x is in $l^2$,... Thanks for the help